# Error while running a SGD optimizer for building CNN

Tags: python, sgd

i get following error while running a SGD optimizer for building a CNN

--> 146 optimizer = SGD(0.01, 0.8, 0.0005, nesterov=True)
147 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
148 #Train the model

TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'nesterov'

Answer (score 0):

[keras SGD](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/sgd/) optimizer has 3 parameters and it accept kwargs so it better to give keys to your parameter.

```
tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False, name="SGD")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem does not solve after changing the code. You have to upgrade Keras and  use it this way

```
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.8, decay=0.0005, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```